# How do I Git Commit all (.) except one file?

Tags: git

Hi all I have done git rm on few files and have modified one file. I want to know how can I do `git commit .` to commit deleted files with excluding the modified file.

Is there anything like

```
git commit -m "Files deleted" . -exclude scripts/process_old_FBA_orders.php
```

Below is my git status

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    help/he_about.html
    deleted:    help/he_glossary.html
    deleted:    help/he_index.html
    deleted:    help/he_jadmin/ad_index.html
    deleted:    help/he_jadmin/ad_server_info.html
    deleted:    help/he_jadmin/ad_users.html
    deleted:    help/he_orders/or_index.html
    deleted:    help/he_products/pr_index.html
    deleted:    help/he_reports/re_index.html
    deleted:    help/he_setup/se_index.html
    deleted:    help/he_stock/st_index.html
    deleted:    help/he_stock/st_needed_items.html
    deleted:    help/he_stock/st_purchase_orders.html
    deleted:    help/he_stock/st_stock_orders.html
    deleted:    help/he_stock/st_stocked_items.html
    deleted:    help/he_stock/st_suppliers.html
    deleted:    help/he_stock/st_suppliers_items.html

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   scripts/process_old_FBA_orders.php
```

Comment: just commit, your modified file is not staged

Comment: Just to mention, `git commit -m 'some message'` is generally a bad idea, with or without specifying paths to commit.  A good commit message usually won't fit on a single line.  :P  And letting the editor fire up also lets you see what's about to be committed.

Comment: You want to commit deletion of help files, but not changes in scripts? In this case you could simply do `git commit -m 'Files deleted' help/`

Answer (score 4):

If its only one or two files I see its easy to add all files then reset unwanted files.

```
$ cd /path/to/repo
$ git add .
$ git reset /path/to/unwanted/file 
$ git commit -m 'commit message'
```

You can reset a whole directory  `$ git reset /path/to/directory/`

Answer (score 2):

Just run `git commit -m "Files deleted"`. Changes not staged for commit (as specified in `git status`) are not committed.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but only applicable to the exact situation the OP ran into. I.e. it is not a generic answer and dependent on a state similar to what the OP has: a set of deleted files and one changed file. IF it were trying to answer the more generic title, then it would be missing information to be complete.